# How to click a span text using selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have been trying to use selenium python to click the continue button in Login Page from the below link.

https://www.makemytrip.com

I have tried several selectors, xpath..nothing seems working for me.

This is the element I am trying to click on:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Continue']").click()
```

Tried with Div class too:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'appendBottom25 ')]")
```

I expect the selenium to click the continue button and to load to the password page

Comment: What's the error message shown?

Comment: it doesn't show any error messages. The page stays till the username keys

Comment: @user10813834 : can you try my solution ... I got the fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **You are using right xpath**

**Solution :**

perform the click operation twice :

```
element =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Continue']")

element.click()
element.click()
```

> It is a strange solution but .. I got solved this problem same way
>   only.

Comment: Perfect !! it works . But why it works for 2 clicks

Comment: @user10813834 : I am looking into it ... Will let you know .. if i got something

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="SW"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/button/span").click()
```

if you choose to find element by xpath you have to pass as argument the xpath. (you right-click on the continue button > `inspect` > and then right click on the elemnt that marked > `copy xpath`)

Comment: I have tried but the page not moving after entering the username and no error message too

Comment: try these too:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="SW"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/button").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/button").click()

Comment: It says Unable to locate element: //*[@id='SW']/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/button

Answer (score 0):

I think you should click on "button".

Try to use xpath below:

> //button[./span[text()='Continue']]

And use explicit wait to wait element to be clickable.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[./span[text()='Continue']]"))).click()
```